# Will an edit fail a First Questions review audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, first-questions

I am doing some first question reviews with tag filters to only show me languages I'm familiar with (I can't tell how good a question is if I fundamentally don't understand what's being asked).

I keep seeing test questions which are "good" and would require positive interaction to pass the test.

However it seems to be picking "good" questions from any language, then showing it to me as if it had the language tag of what I've filtered.

For example I'll see a well formed question asking about [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), and it will have the Haskell tag, and the C# tag when in the review (clicking on the question link shows the C# tag isn't on the actual question, only on my review test).

My first instinct is to edit the tags to remove this obviously wrong tag, questions being in the wrong language tags are a nuisance to everyone.

However this in the past has caused me to fail the test as it’s not a positive interaction, and now I'm too scared to see if it still would cause this.

I find myself meta-gaming the review (so to speak) and not editing tags at all until I've checked if it’s a review test.

Am I approaching this wrong? Should I avoid these kinds of edits? Or is this an oversight in the review test system?

Comment: If you're working hard enough to game audits you're probably working hard enough. They're designed to make sure you're paying attention, and you were attentive enough to see what was going on. If SE weren't happy with you doing this, they'd make a better system for audits.

Comment: "I can't tell how good a question is if I fundamentally don't understand what's being asked". If only more people here on SO had that logic.

Comment: I have this same problem. I apply a very strict set of filters when reviewing, and the audit system will always just shove my tags onto otherwise-good questions in other languages. (language + some libraries)  Just "skip" them as obviously bad attempts at auto-generating audits. If the system isn't going to make an effort, why should you?

Comment: I would just skip it.

Comment: *"this in the past has caused me to fail the test as its not a positive interaction"* [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26006269) is the only known-good audit you've ever failed, for context.

Comment: Related: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](/q/288046/4642212) and its linked questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Editing in First Questions will always pass an audit

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31465726) is an example of a known-good audit passed by editing, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31456879) is an example of a known-bad audit passed by editing, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33530267) is an example a known-spam audit passed by editing.

---

<sup>Special thanks to Henry Ecker for [finding these example audits](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54307965#54307965).</sup>

Comment: This seems like itself an abusable loophole - just go through the queue and hit Edit on everything, no need to actually change anything in the edit. Or at least, it would, if there were any actual reward for doing these queues in the first place.