# Suspended from reviewing due to audit showing wrong tag

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I've recently started doing reviews.

[image: Screenshot]

In the first audit, I honestly do not remember where I did wrong, but I failed as the system correctly recognized.

The second audit had a wrong tag (*[Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flutter/info)*), and I wanted to remove it by doing an edit. The problem is that my edit queue is full since yesterday (there are still pending edits since April 17th), so I tried leaving a comment advising the original poster to retag correctly. I did not flag immediately the question because of the 10 times limit (also; the post was fine, the only problem was a wrong tag).

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31588213

My intent was to post a custom feedback, I don't get how could the system know if it would have been good or bad for the audit.

I've received a two-day suspension because of this.

I'm not complaining, but being new to this my question is: should I have flagged the question instead of trying to leave a comment? Also, shouldn't reviewers have access to a slightly bigger queue of edits (or flags)?

Anyway, I will definitely be more careful next time, I really like doing reviews.

Thanks for any clarification.

### Edit

[Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson)

> it is possible for audits to [deliberately show you the wrong tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223853/review-audit-honeypot-messes-with-tags-leads-to-wrong-comments-left) if
> you filter reviews by tag

[samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2777074/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz)

> If you have set a tag filter in the reviews, audits will get retagged
> to match your filter if there are not enough potential audits in your
> tags.

So why is the system telling me I failed the audit if the tag was *actually* wrong?

Comment: Flagging would have failed the audit too, the question is perceived (by the audit system) as a good question. You say that you were going to provide feedback to the question; what feedback were you going to provide to improve the question in the [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31588213)? If you were going to flag it, what were you going to flag it as?

Comment: Part of this is addressed in [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412271/6083675).

Comment: @Larnu The question had a "flutter" tag but was not at all related to flutter. I was trying to share feedback to in order to advice the OP of the problem

Comment: That [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71756300/timeline) has never been tagged with [[tag:flutter]], @Dani3le_ .

Comment: Neither of the reviews were for questions tagged as [tag:flutter].

Comment: I had the [flutter] tag active at the time and the question had the flutter tag. I still got the page open, here's the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/VskMNuc.png

Comment: That screenshot is showing the review filter, not the question's tags. Was the tag also shown on the question itself? If so, I can see how that would mislead one to try and remove it...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, it was, that's what I'm trying to say. I'm 100% sure, otherwise I wouldn't have made this question in the first place. Also, I was reviewing with the [flutter] tag, so seeing a c++ question was an alert that a tag was not correct

Comment: Like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223853/review-audit-honeypot-messes-with-tags-leads-to-wrong-comments-left

Comment: If you have set a tag filter in the reviews, audits will get retagged to match your filter if there are not enough potential audits in your tags. I get python questions as audits all the time because there aren't any possible audits in the filter I set.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok, but why is the system telling me I failed if the tag was *actually* wrong?

Comment: I'm not at all surprised the suggested edit queue when people are filling it up with garbage like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7O1C.png

Comment: It is a bit weird that the system can add tags to "known good" posts. This results in a bad audit. A question can't be "ok" when it has a wrong tag, but actions to remove that tag may end with a failed audit.

Comment: As a workaround until this broken system gets fixed (don't hold your breath), any time you see a question with the wrong tags, open it up in another tab to check if it's an audit.

Comment: Tip: when you think a question in the review queue has a wrong tag, or something else seems fishy, open the actual question!

Comment: Always open a review task in another tab.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The suspension was automatic for failing two audits (and you really did fail that first one, but you've acknowledged it).

The catch on the second is what we call a "known good" audit. The system sees "Hey, this got a lot of upvotes so it must be good!" and puts it out there as an audit where anything other than "Looks OK" is unacceptable. I'm not sure what annotation you felt was necessary, but I've not been fond of review suspensions for merely failing to meet the arbitrary "Looks OK" standard.

I've lifted your review suspension this time. But please do learn from that first failure. The question was off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about how the system works. About the first failure: yes, I do know I did wrong and I will definitely learn from that. Thank you very much for the answer and for lifting my suspension.

Comment: *"anything other than "Looks OK" is unacceptable"* - isn't edit also a valid choice?

Comment: @MrMythical I can't check presently, but I want to say the system doesn't see Edit as a valid choice in a "known good" audit

Comment: [For FQQ Edit will always pass an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417233/15497888).

Comment: @HenryEcker Good find. TIL.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there's actually anything wrong with the tags on that question, although it is possible for audits to [deliberately show you the wrong tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223853/review-audit-honeypot-messes-with-tags-leads-to-wrong-comments-left) if you filter reviews by tag. If audits didn't do that then you might be able to prevent the system from auditing you at all if there wasn't a suitably tagged post that you could be presented with.

Having said that, if you can't edit and you think the question needs an edit then skip and let someone else who has [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) do the necessary edit.

If we made the queue bigger it would simply fill up to the new size and then we'd be back to square 1, wouldn't we? The answer has to be to persuade more people to do more edit queue reviews.

As to your first review

- It asks a lot of questions
- It contains spelling mistakes and has capitalisation issues with I
- One of the commenters suggests that the OP needs to explain what they mean by overtakes

So why did you think it was OK?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've never said I did ok in the first audit, I know that I failed it.

Comment: Thanks for the Information about the audits to deliberately showing you the wrong tag!

Comment: "audits to deliberately show you the wrong tag if you filter reviews by tag" - Yep, I see this a lot! I filter the review queues with rather niche tags. Then suddenly a completely unrelated question pops up with one of these niche tags "stuck" on it (and upvotes artificially reduced to 0)! The natural reaction is to edit/remove the "incorrect" tag or leave a comment (as you would do in the real world), but this fails the audit - which is just bizarre. Fortunately, these type of gotcha-audits become easy to spot, but they are usually just a trigger for me to stop reviewing at that point.

Comment: To be clear, the author isn't referring to the overall edit queue size, but the limit that they can only have five suggested edits pending at one time.

Comment: Sure, it would take time for the edit to be reviewed, but at least they'd be able to complete the review and pass the audit. (Also, edits submitted in review audits are ignored and not actually submitted, so they wouldn't be stuck with an additional item waiting to be reviewed.)

Comment: @gparyani not sure you're getting my point. If there's a limit be it 500 pending edits globally or 5 per person then sometime you'll hit it and then you're stuck. Increasing the limit won't help much because you'll just hit the higher limit.

Comment: My point is, even though a user's personal edit limit is full, on review audits, it should behave the same, allowing to open the edit form and not submitting the edit, since it isn't going to take up another spot. This way, the audit can be passed even if the user's personal limit is full.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @gparyani yes, that was exactly my suggestion.